# nginx – proxy_pass from /subfolder – destination files 404'ing. Rewrite rule req?

Tags: nginx, nuxt.js, nginx-config

I have two servers running nginx:

Server 1 has a range of projects on it
Server 2 has a new Vue/Nuxtjs (node)

On server 1 I have set up a `proxy_pass` to the static IP of server 2 where my node based app is running. So the goal is for users to just see `http://domain.tld/folder`, `http://domain.tld/folder/login` etc when they browse the site

Server 1:

```
location /folder/ { 
  proxy_pass http://200.1.1.1/; // IP of server 2
}
```

Server 2:

```
location / {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
}
```

This works partly but all assets are 404. And when clicking links the browser visits `http://domain.tld/login`

[Update]
Full server 2 nginx config (commented some stuff out to avoid conflicts):

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443;


# set path to your project dir
  set $root_path /root/app;

# static content directory
  root $root_path/client/nuxt-dist/dist;

# proxy to nuxt renderer
  try_files $uri $uri/ @nodeproxy;

  location @nodeproxy {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
  }

# entry point for API server, if you have one
  location /api {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
    client_max_body_size 3m;
  }

# serve nuxt bundle with max cache life. Only compatible with nuxt 2.*
#  location ~^\/_nuxt(.*)$ {
#    alias $root_path/client/.nuxt/dist/client/$1;
#    gzip on;
#    gzip_comp_level 6;
#    gzip_vary on;
#    gzip_types text/css application/json application/javascript text/javascript application/x-font-ttf font/opentype;
#    expires max;
#  }

# serve static content
  location ~* \.(js|jpg|jpeg|txt|png|css|pdf|ico|map)$ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires 30d;
  }

# refirect from /path/ to /path
#  rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
}
```

Comment: are assets on server1 or server2?

Comment: @PavelLint  They are on server 2, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Update: here's how to achieve this:

```
server {
  try_files $uri $uri/ @nodeproxy;

  location @nodeproxy {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks, it says there's too many redirects. In safari it says something like `http://domain.tld/folder/folder/folder/folder`

Comment: Am still seeing the same issue - do we need to add the subdirectory to the `try_files` line?

Comment: could be cache, try a different file maybe? This should work

Comment: I've added my server 2 nginx config to my main post, Have tried clearing cache, restarting nginx etc. I think I have implemented your solution correctly - any other ideas?